# 22.04 / HP Omen 17 / RGB Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, i2c

Help,sometime in the recent past, my RGB keyboard sort of stopped working, it only works in breathing mode which I am assuming is the default mode when not connected. The keyboard used to work fine, you could only turn it off / on and not control the color but that was better than this on-off breathing mode.

I installed OpenRGB which fails to detect the keyboard and complains that i2c-dev is not installed. I also installed an hp-wmi driver from https://github.com/pelrun/hp-omen-linux-module.git

Neither seemed to work.
In trying to debug this I noticed that my Nvidia drivers stopped working as well sometime in the past. They were stuck at v515 when the latest is v525. I installed v525 and it required me to enable / enroll secure boot. I am including Nvidia driver info in case it has relevant info now that I have secure boot enabled,

Some system details

**OMEN by HP 17 Laptop PC**

```
Product number: 6M0U7AV
•Full-size, per key RGB backlit, shadow black keyboard with NKRO Anti-Ghosting Key technology and optical switch
•Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX211 (2x2) and Bluetooth 5.2 combo
•Intel Core i7-12800HX (up to 4.8 GHz, 25 MB L3 cache, 16 cores, 24 threads) + NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU (8 GB)
```

**sudo dkms status**

```
hp-omen-wmi/0.9, 5.15.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/525.60.11, 5.15.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
openrazer-driver/3.2.0, 5.15.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.38, 5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.38, 5.15.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**lsmod | grep i2c**

```
 - i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
 - i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
 - i2c_i801               36864  0
 - i2c_hid                36864  1 i2c_hid_acpi
 - i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
 - hid                   151552  5 
 - i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic,uhid
```

**nvidia-debugdump -l**

```
Found 1 NVIDIA devices
    Device ID:              0
    Device name:            NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU
    GPU internal ID:        GPU-86caef18-91ef-9478-143d-b277631bb11b
```

**nvidia-smi**

```
NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.11    Driver Version: 525.60.11    CUDA Version: 12.0
```

**inxi**

```
 - CPU: 16-core (8-mt/8-st) 12th Gen Intel Core i7-12800HX (-MST AMCP-)
 - speed/min/max: 683/800/6000:6100:3400 MHz Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64
 - Up: 55m Mem: 3489.8/63978.9 MiB (5.5%) Storage: 3.73 TiB (34.2% used)
 - Procs: 461 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

**i2cdetect -l**

```
i2c-0   smbus       SMBus I801 adapter at efa0          SMBus adapter
i2c-1   i2c         Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter     I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         i915 gmbus dpa                      I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         i915 gmbus dpb                      I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         i915 gmbus dpc                      I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         i915 gmbus tc1                      I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         i915 gmbus tc2                      I2C adapter
i2c-7   i2c         i915 gmbus tc3                      I2C adapter
i2c-8   i2c         i915 gmbus tc4                      I2C adapter
i2c-9   i2c         i915 gmbus tc5                      I2C adapter
i2c-10  i2c         i915 gmbus tc6                      I2C adapter
i2c-11  i2c         AUX A/DDI A/PHY A                   I2C adapter
i2c-12  i2c         NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0      I2C adapter
i2c-13  i2c         NVIDIA i2c adapter 3 at 1:00.0      I2C adapter
i2c-14  i2c         NVIDIA i2c adapter 4 at 1:00.0      I2C adapter
i2c-15  i2c         NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at 1:00.0      I2C adapter
i2c-16  i2c         NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at 1:00.0      I2C adapter
i2c-17  i2c         NVIDIA i2c adapter 7 at 1:00.0      I2C adapter
```